# How to add `pod install` step to ios build process

Tags: ios, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I have just installed a dependency in my react-native project that required manual configuration of `ios/Podfile`.

If I have a fresh clone of the repository for this project, `react-native run-ios` will fail to work until I run `pod install` within the context of the ios folder. I'd like to get that to automatically happen as part of the ios build instead of being a separate step.

I've tried adding `pod install` as a "Run Script" in xcode and moved it to the top of the build order, but no luck with that.

How can I add a `pod install` step to the ios build process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to specify a separate script in your package scripts:

```
{
  "name": "Awesome Project",
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start-ios": "cd ./ios && pod install && cd .. && react-native run-ios",
  },
  ...some other stuff here...
}
```

P.S. It doesn't seem to be wise to install pods whenever you want to build an app. It requires many redundant steps, and you want to consider just including pods sources in your repository, that is way better IMHO. (if installing pods once after clonning the repo is not an option)

Comment: That is what I did as a work-around. I think that it really belongs in the ios build process, not a separate step in my scripts.

Comment: @davidpricedev, nope. `pod install` is kind of 3-rd party stuff. Running it as a build script also seems to be a bad idea, because this command changes project iOS files (*.xcodeproj / *.xcworkspace)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question OP asked. It suggests they do it a _different_ way, which is not helpful